# Redux-form-material-ui - use Select with onChange

Tags: reactjs, onchange, material-ui, redux-form

I'm using redux-form-material-ui 5.0.0-beta.2 which is compatible with material ui v1.

I want to have a Select component where I can activate an onChange event when a choice is made, and I want the selected value to show in the Select field (as it should). If I use the redux-form-material-ui Select component I get the error:

```
Cannot read property 'onChange' of undefined
```

I can reproduce it by taking the example on how to use redux-form with material ui [here](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/material-ui/) and replace the SelectField with redux-form-material-ui Select and put {children} between the open and close tag. You can see the same error:

[Code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zr873j8x6p)

^^ If you open this in Chrome you get the "`Cannot read property 'onChange'..`" error, but in Firefox it says "`_ref$input is undefined`".

Can this be fixed in some way:

```
import { Select } from 'redux-form-material-ui';

const renderSelectField = (
  { input, label, meta: { touched, error }, children, ...custom },
) => (
    <Select 
      errorText={touched && error}
      {...input}
      onChange={(event, index, value) => input.onChange(value)}

      {...custom}
    >
      {children}
    </Select>
); 
const MaterialUiForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

      <div>
        <Field
          name="favoriteColor"
          component={renderSelectField}
          label="Favorite Color"
        >
          <MenuItem value="ff0000" primaryText="Red" />
          <MenuItem value="00ff00" primaryText="Green" />
          <MenuItem value="0000ff" primaryText="Blue" />
        </Field>
      </div>

//code continues..
```

If I try a simpler approach using the example on redux-form-material-ui:
[redux-form-material-ui/tree/5.0](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form-material-ui/tree/5.0)

```
<Field 
    name="plan" 
    component={Select}
    onChange={(event, index, value) => input.onChange(value)} 
    placeholder="Select a plan"
>
    <MenuItem value="monthly">Monthly</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value="yearly">Yearly</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value="lifetime">Lifetime</MenuItem>
  </Field>
```

But it doesn't work if I add the onChange. When doing a selection it says:

```
props.input is undefined
```

Comment: according to docs its `SelectField` not `Select` https://github.com/erikras/redux-form-material-ui

Answer (score 0):

You probably looked up the example in official Redux Form docs, but, just how it has been mentioned in the comment, they used **SelectedField** instead of **Select** component.

SelectField implements *onChange* method with **3 arguments**, however **Select** uses just one. Use this instead.

```
onChange={value => input.onChange(value)}
```